# How to run lsqlite3 example

Tags: sqlite, debugging, lua, package

I have downloaded LUA 5.1 and lsqlite3 source code and easily prepared a Visual C++ express project which compiles and runs fine, adding to it SQLite3 and lsqlite3 (just few more .c and .h files).

I am using lua.c as entry point with its "main" function, and I have removed from the visual studio project luac.c file. When I launch the .exe it shows me a command line that parses basic lua commands (such as `print("hello world")`), and this works fine.
Launching one of the standard Lua (5.1) example works fine as well (e.g. typing `dofile("bisec.lua")`), but if I try one .lua file from lsqlite3 I have the following error:

```
statement.lua:1: module 'lsqlite3' not found:
        no field package.preload['lsqlite3']
        no file '.\lsqlite3.lua'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\lua\lsqlite3.lua'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\lua\lsqlite3\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\lsqlite3.lua'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\lsqlite3\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\lsqlite3.luac'
        no file '.\lsqlite3.dll'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\lsqlite3.dll'
        no file 'C:\Projects\lua-5.1.5_lsqlite3_integration\lua_5.1_lsqlite3_int
egration\Debug\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        statement.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

How do I register lsqlite3 package?
I found a file which I am suspecting has something to do with this that is:"lsqlite3-0.8-1.rockspec"
but I do not if it is useful to my purpose nor how to use it.

Comment: Put the answer in an *answer*, not the question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. It's OK to answer your own question, but you need to do that by using the "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I got it.
>
> Add "LUA_API int luaopen_lsqlite3(lua_State *L) ;" to lua.h
>
> in file lua.c, in function "static int pmain (lua_State *L)" after the line "luaL_openlibs(L); /* open libraries */" add the line "luaopen_lsqlite3(L);"
>
> Change the first line in all of the lsqlite3 example files from "require("lsqlite3")" to "require("sqlite3")"
>
> Doing these 3 points had the example scripts run fine, or at least with no error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load sqlite3 sources and build them -> sqlite3.dll will be yours.
2. Load lsqlite sources and build them (that will need sqlite3.a and some headers) -> you will get lsqlite3.dll.
3. Put lsqlite3.dll to your Lua clibs directory (\Lua\5.1\clibs)
4. Try this:

   ```
   require("lsqlite3")
   local db = assert( sqlite3:open_memory() )
   ```